# replace character for getting only the image-url failed

Tags: javascript

I want to do a simple thing: Remove all characters which are from a URL.

For example, I have this:

```
var el['background-image'].style_value='url "https://www.example.com/dir/dir/file.JPG"';
```

And at the end i want to have only: https://www.example.com/dir/dir/file.JPG

I tried it in these ways...

```
console.log('test1 '+el['background-image'].style_value.replace('url(\"', '').replace('\")', ''));
console.log('test2 '+el['background-image'].style_value.replace('\")', ''));
console.log('test3 '+el['background-image'].style_value.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, ''));
```

...but all failed and return the string as it is.

```
url "https://www.example.com/dir/dir/file.JPG"
```

Thanks for helping and telling what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: how do you want your answer to look like

Comment: sorry, what you mean? At the end i wont to have only the http:......jpg

Comment: add your expected output.

Comment: its done, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
let str = 'url "https://www.example.com/dir/dir/file.JPG"';

str = str.replace(/url|"|\b/g, '');
console.log(str)
```